# Rails: Partial Rendering with Ajax not working - Commenting System Like FB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I made a commenting system that would comment under a micropost but the issue is that the whole page refreshes rather than just the comment section area like facebook does it. I think it may have to do with my create.js but I am not sure. Any suggestions will be much appreciated! Thank you!

This is my current js for the **create.js**:

`$("#comments").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @micropost.comments)) %>");`

**comment controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save 
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

**Comment Section**

```
<div id='CommentContainer-<%= micropost.id%>' class='CommentContainer Condensed2'>
<div class='Comment'>
<%= render :partial => "comments/form", :locals => { :micropost => micropost } %>
</div>
<div id='comments'>
<%=render micropost.comments %>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the comments form is being submitted remotely (`:remote => true`) and that your comments section is equipped to handle the response from the server and that the form function responds to js/json

Comment: Mmm I forgot that! Thanks again but why does it post two comments and store two comments rather than just one?

Comment: That means that somewhere along the way the request is being sent twice either by the form or in the controller.